# Send generated html email to Outlook clients without getting it reformatted

Tags: c#, outlook, html-email

I am attempting to send html-formatted emails generated in a C# web app to Outlook clients.  These messages include html tables and images.

The tables and the images come through, but Outlook changes the formatting of the tables and screws them up (it adds additional line breaks and other elements).

How can I force Outlook clients to retain the original html formatting?

Here is the html content I am trying to include:

```
<div style='font-family: arial;'>
  <table style='border-collapse:collapse;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
    <tr style='height: 180px;'>
      <td style='width:1.65in; border:none; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;' valign='top'>
        <p style='margin: 2px; font-size:12.0pt; color:#002060; text-align:center' align='center'><b>%name%</b></p>
        <p style='margin: 2px; font-size:11.0pt; color:#002060; text-align:center' align='center'>%title%</p>
        <p style='margin: 20px;'> </p>
        <p><img src='cid:logo' alt='TUV USA Logo' style='width: 118; height: 103;'></p>
      </td>
      <td style='width:148.85pt; padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;' valign='top'>
        <p><b><span style='font-size:12.0pt; color:#002060'>TUV USA, Inc.</span></b></p>
        <p> </p>
        <p style='margin: 2px; font-size:8.0pt; color:#1F497D'>215 Main Street</p>
        <p style='margin: 2px; font-size:8.0pt; color:#1F497D'>Salem, NH 03079</p>
        <p style='margin: 2px; font-size:8.0pt; color:#1F497D'>United States of America</p>
        <p> </p>
        <p style='font-size:8.0pt; color:#1F497D'>Phone: 603-870-8023</p>
        <p> </p>
        <p><a href='mailto:%emailaddress%' target='_blank'><span style='font-size:8.0pt; color:#1F4E79; text-decoration:none'>%emailaddress%</span></a></p>
        <p><a href='http://www.tuv-usa.com/' target='_blank'><span style='font-size:8.0pt; color:#1F497D; text-decoration:none'>www.tuv-usa.com</span></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try to use <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"><html><head><title></title><META http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"></head>

Comment: I tried adding the above text but it didn't help

Comment: Hi Richard, you are using paragragh tags with margins. Each email client has different way of reading/rendering it. You font size and paragraph margins might be throwing the spaces off. Try removing the paragraph tags and replace them with break tags. Break tags are read the same across all email clients.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"><html><head><title></title><META http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"></head>
<body>
  --mail Content....
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: The following was tested with Outlook 2016 & Thunderbird*

**CSS Formatting**

**EDIT**: *Fixed the reset code below, please try it.*

Do you provide any styling information in your HTML (CSS?).
Try to reset your table/div with something like this:

```
style="margin:0;padding:0;border: 0;"
```

I have a very similar scenario, and I don't have the issue you are describing. The only thing I noticed is that Outlook ignores some more advanced CSS style information, like shadows.
Every browser has its standard of displaying content (different margin, padding, ...). You can reset these settings by forcing them to 0 with the code above.

In case of a `<table>` there are also other style settings that might influence the look of it when viewed in different browsers/mail-clients,
the cell and column spacing for example.

**Code**

Make sure that in case of `MailMessage` you are setting the `IsBodyHtml` property to `true`. Else HTML content might get displayed as text.

**Example**

The following is the HTML code I use in my case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>##[TITLE]##</title>
    <style>
        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
        a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
        del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
        small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
        b, u, i, center,
        dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend,
        table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
        figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
        menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        p {
            margin: 4px;
        }

        /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
        article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }

        body {
            line-height: 1;
        }

        ol, ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        blockquote, q {
            quotes: none;
        }

            blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
            q:before, q:after {
                content: '';
                content: none;
            }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        .ellipsis {
            height: 12px;
            padding-left: 2px;
            padding-right: 2px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            // IE 6+, FF 7+, Op 11+, Saf 1.3+, Chr 1+ -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
            // for Opera 9 & 10;
        }

        tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: lightcyan;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="border:1px;border-color:black;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px #888888;margin:12px">
    <header>
        <div style="padding:12px;padding-top:8px">
            <h5>##[TITLE]##</h5>
            <span style="font-size:11px">Started on ##[START]## - Ended on ##[END]## (##[DURATION]##)</span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div style="margin-left:12px;margin-right:12px;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana">
            <p>Products: ##[PRODUCT_COUNT]##</p>
            <p style="font-size:11px">Articles: ##[ARTICLE_COUNT]##</p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:12px;margin-left:12px;margin-right:12px;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana">
            <p style="font-size:11px;color:darkred">Failures: ##[FAILURE_COUNT]##</p>
            <table style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px;margin-left:12px;margin-right:100px;width:97%;table-layout:fixed">
                ##[FAILURE_ROWS]##
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:12px;margin-left:12px;margin-right:12px;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana">
            <p style="font-size:11px;color:orange">Warnings: ##[WARNING_COUNT]##</p>
            <table style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px;margin-left:12px;margin-right:100px;width:97%;table-layout:fixed">
                ##[WARNING_ROWS]##
            </table>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div style="padding:12px;padding-bottom:8px;color:gray">
            <h6>Check the attachment of this e-mail for more details.</h6>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Placeholders like `##[TITLE]##` will be replaced by `string.Replace` with the proper value during generation of the email body.
This is particularly important in case of `##[FAILURE_ROWS]##` and `##[WARNING_ROWS]##` which are replaced by several of the following strings:

```
string row = "<tr>" +
            "<td class=\"ellipsis\" style=\"width:95px;color:gray\">" + time + "</td>" +
            "<td class=\"ellipsis\" style=\"width:30%\">" + Entry.Value1 + "</td>" +
            "<td class=\"ellipsis\" style=\"width:80px;color:gray\">" + Entry.Value2 + "</td>" +
            "<td class=\"ellipsis\" style=\"width:30%;color:gray\">" + Entry.Value3 + "</td>" +
            "<td style=\"width:70%\">" +
                "<div class=\"ellipsis\" style=\"max-width:90%\">" +
                    Entry.Message + 
                "</div>" +
            "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
```

Once all placeholders are replaced with generated and properly formatted HTML code there should be no issues whatsoever.

HTH

Comment: I am using MailMessage, and the IsBodyHtml flag is set to true.  But I am not using CSS in this case - all of the styling is inline. I modified my original post to include the html text I am trying to include.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you did all that inline, instead of including style sheet in a `<head>` tag? Did you try to "reset" those `<p>` tags with the CSS I mentioned in the first part of my answer? That can also be done inline, no style sheet needed. Also please don't just use a `<div>`, use a proper HTML document (including `<html>`, `<body>`, ...) , take a look at the one in my answer.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the results you are getting when the HTML code is viewed in Outlook?